# Working with search suggestion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, search

I have the following search suggestion script, where as a user types dynamically the result is updated. What I would want is that when a user click on one of the suggestion it takes them to the following:`searchPage.php?user_query=what the user has typed in the input`

**Below is the script:**

```
$(function () {
    $(".search").keyup(function () {
        var searchid = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'search=' + searchid;
        if (searchid != '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {
                    $("#result").html(html).show();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });

    jQuery("#result").live("click", function (e) {
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
        var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
        $('#searchid').val(decoded);
    });
    jQuery(document).live("click", function (e) {
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        if (!$clicked.hasClass("search")) {

            window.open('searchPage.php?user_query=', '_self', false);
        }
    });
    $('#searchid').click(function () {
        jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

At its current state it just open the window to searchPage.php but doesn't take into account in the url what the user has entered. The desired result is `searchPage.php?user_query=what ever you want`

**Update:**

```
<form method="get" action="searchPage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" class="search" id="searchid" name="user_query" id="searchBar" placeholder="Search for courses"/>
    <input type="submit" id="searchButton" name="search" value="search" class="btn btn-danger" autocomplete="off"/>

    <div id="result"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can include `html` ?

Comment: Which element , when `click`ed , should open new `window` ?

Comment: the search suggestion within result

Comment: essentially where the window.open is located but adding the value of the searchid input to the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of the search string like this:

```
document.getElementById('searchid').value
```

So, appending it to your query would look something like this:

```
window.open('searchPage.php?user_query=' + document.getElementById('searchid').value,'_self',false);
```

Depending on what is in the search box, you might have some issues to address, such as a search term that includes the `&` symbol (e.g. ?user_query=search&find for example would only come across as search on the server) - you don't want to accidentally pass an extra param that you intend to be part of the search string. To address you might convert that character:

```
var searchString = document.getElementById('searchid').value.replace(/&amp;/g,'&')
window.open('searchPage.php?user_query=' + searchString,'_self',false);
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. i've followed it, but when i click on it gives me the following url searchPage.php?user_query= disregarding the searchstring all together

Comment: looking at your HTML I notice that you have two IDs in your input field - you should only have one (the JS probably isnt finding the input field - you can provide the JS error here for more feedback). The code above assumes it is `searchid` but you can change that to whatever you update your HTML to be (I'd guess either searchid or searchBar): `<input type="text" class="search" id="searchid" name="user_query" id="searchBar" placeholder="Search for courses" />`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
// `searchid` variable available to `keyup`, `click` event handlers
var searchid = "";
var input = $("#searchid");
var results = $("#results");

input.on("keyup", function(e) {

  searchid = e.target.value;
  results.text(searchid)

});

results.on("click", function(e) {
  var popup = window.open("searchPage.php?user_query=" 
                          + searchid, "_self", false);
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hxehczpq/1/